# Default Select list value in Combo box - LWC

Tags: salesforce, custom-element, salesforce-lightning

I have created a combo-box in LWC for which, I want to default a value.The options for the LWC are fetched from controller. I tried the following & it dint work. I have removed the "placeholder="-Select-", but still OOB i see a place holder "Select a value". I want to remove the OOB placeholder & also default it to a particular value on load.

```
                  <lightning-combobox required
                        label="Values"
                        class="value"  
                        value={choosenValue}
                        options={choosenValueOptions}
                        onchange={handleValueChange} >
                    </lightning-combobox>
```

TIA,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Add in the Javascript code the default value:

```
export default class ComboboxBasic extends LightningElement {
    @track chosenValue = 'defautValue';
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Sunil, yes but you need to rename the value variable (to `choosenValue`). I've updated the answer.